# shells vs command interpreters vs command line?

Tags: operating-system

what is the different between shells and command interpreters and command line?

I read in concepts of operating systems book this sentence:

On systems with multiple command interpreters to choose from, the interpreters are know as shells.

could someone explain what it means?

Comment: shell is a specific kind of command line interpreter. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interpreter#Command-line_interpreter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On UNIX-like systems, such as Linux, there are many command interpreters available, such as `sh`, `csh`, `ksh` or `bash`. Each user can choose which to have as a default. The term `shell`, which originally designated the single command interpreter available, comes from the notion that the UNIX architecture is layered and is often depicted as a set of concentric spheres; the inner one, the one that is closest to the hardware, is the *kernel*, the outer one, which at the time provided the only interface available to the user, is the *shell*.

As other command interpreters became available they were all referred to as *shells* and it became an informal convention for them to have the `sh` character sequence in their name.